# How to make text vertical align to the bottom in floating divs?

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to solve this for a couple of hours now and I cannot get it to work.

I have a floated left & right div. The right div contains an image and the left div contains text. The image & text swap left & right according to the users preference, which is why i am using float.

**How do I position the text to be at the bottom of the wrapper but next to the image?**

I have a visual display below:

**[image: x]**

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class"text">Text aligned at bottom</div>
    <div class="photo"><img id="photograph" src="" width="140px" height="140px" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it ok to add addition html?

Comment: Yes. Whatever you think is necessary to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added a `<div class="inner">`, and set it as `display:table-cell` + `vertical-align:bottom`, see the following demo and snippet.

**Edit:** also added `calc()` to make the photo div is only as wide as the width of the photo and the text div takes up all of the remaining width automatically.

**[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sr2ajsLh/)**

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
.wrapper .text {
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 140px);
}
.wrapper .photo {
    float: right;
}
.wrapper .inner {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 140px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.wrapper .inner img {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text">
        <div class="inner">Text aligned at bottom, text aligned at bottom, text aligned at bottom, text aligned at bottom, text aligned at bottom.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="photo">
        <div class="inner"><img id="photograph" src="//dummyimage.com/140" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```